# Add item to list via inspector

Tags: unity-game-engine

Say I have an array:

```
public GameObject[] objects = new GameObject[10];
```

Then in the inspector I can manually assign each of the array elements with a GameObject and set up references that way.

Suppose I want this array to be a list instead. Since lists aren't initialized with length/size, I can't seem to assign the references this way via the inspector. I can set the size of the list and assign references in the inspector but it returns to an empty list at runtime.

I want to use a list and not an array for this problem. How do I solve this one inspector reference assignment problem?

Comment: I've never encountered this problem. `List` are correctly serialized in the inspector (see [doc](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/script-Serialization.html): _Container field types that can be serialized_). Have you any custom inspector for your class? Are you sure you don't call `objects = new List<GameObject>()` in your `Awake` or `Start` method?

Answer (score 2):

To add a new element in a `List` via the Inspector, you need to drag and drop the element here:

[image]

The reference will be saved and the `Size` will be updated. You can even drag and drop multiple items by Shift/Ctrl + Click selecting them and then dragging them together.

Answer (score 0):

Figured out the issue. Figured out the issue. It was really elementary. I was creating a new empty list in Awake which was "overriding" the inspector updates.